# Executing Powershell script from command prompt without changing environment?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a power shell script to execute one sample script. But when i am running it from command prompt it is changing environment from command prompt to Power shell and executing script. Which i don't want .

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  C:\Users\ic020511\Desktop\Script.ps1
```

Is there any command that would not switch from command prompt and execute script

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? You'll need a powershell host application to run powershell scripts in any case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that using the `start` command:

```
start Powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  C:\Users\ic020511\Desktop\Script.ps1
```

Comment: This initially worked for me .But after i restarted my machine it is not working.eventhough it is not changing environment it is opening new powershell windows

Comment: @user3883423 Parameter '/B' should give you the expected results

Comment: Now again this is changing environment. I don't why it worked on that day why it is not working today..

Comment: @user3883423 can you try `-windowstyle hidden` like above and see if that fits your need?